# Error 403 while accessing data from S3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have uploaded my csv file to the s3 bucket.

I wanted to read the uploaded csv file in R

I am using the below code , and I am getting an error

```
usercsvobj <-get_object("s3.amazonaws.com/wdataset/08.Data.csv.xlsx")

> List of 4  $ Code     : chr "AccessDenied"  $ Message  : chr "Access
> Denied"  $ RequestId: chr "89601C0D6B9BD66E"  $ HostId   : chr
> "jWDPrqCpRkeh5YoaHalHDa2WWmyyJsiSM1orDRnXnWgmgxXV8NGl0ixgUAPTW4M5wC91y52aAgw="
>  - attr(*, "headers")=List of 6   ..$ x-amz-request-id : chr "89601C0D6B9BD66E"   ..$ x-amz-id-2       : chr
> "jWDPrqCpRkeh5YoaHalHDa2WWmyyJsiSM1orDRnXnWgmgxXV8NGl0ixgUAPTW4M5wC91y52aAgw="
> ..$ content-type     : chr "application/xml"   ..$ transfer-encoding:
> chr "chunked"   ..$ date             : chr "Tue, 20 Mar 2018 15:47:35
> GMT"   ..$ server           : chr "AmazonS3"   ..- attr(*, "class")=
> chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "aws_error"
>  - attr(*, "request_canonical")= chr "GET\n/s3.amazonaws.com/wdataset/08.03Data.csv.xlsx/\nlocation=\nhost:s3.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20180320T1547"|
> __truncated__
>  - attr(*, "request_string_to_sign")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180320T154736Z\n20180320/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n446775270ab311e3cd7d1a0855b1592a7437dae"|
> __truncated__
>  - attr(*, "request_signature")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIHS7A4UQKPC3VGEQ/20180320/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,
> SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-d"| __truncated__ NULL Error in
> parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) :    Forbidden (HTTP
> 403).
```

could any one help me to resolve this. its been an hour and i am unable to resolve this error.

Comment: Is this [`aws.s3`](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3)? Do you have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_ACCESS_ACCESS_KEY` set correctly? Can you get to the uploaded file via a web-browser? (I'm assuming your "bucket" is private, so are you able to `get_bucket`?)

Comment: @r2evans yes. I am able to get the uploaded file via web browser

Comment: @Mikz, I am having the same issue. How did you solve it?